# Why am I being prompted for a sudo password when I specified "NOPASSWD" in my /etc/sudoers file?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, password

I’m using Ubuntu 14.04.  I have this in my /etc/sudoers file

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%deployers ALL=(ALL) ALL

rails ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/bundle, /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby, /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake, /usr/bin/service, /sbin/   restart

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

I thought including the above command (the one with “NOPASSWD”) would prevent getting prompted for a password, but after I reboot my system and login as my “rails” user, note I’m still getting asked for a password when running sudo …

```
rails@mymachine:~$ sudo rake db:migrate
[sudo] password for rails: 
rails@mymachine:~$ which rake
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake
```

What do I need to do so I’m not prompted for a password when running the “rake” command (and other commands I listed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` resets your environment by default, so it won't search your `$PATH`. So it might be trying to run a system-default version of `ruby` instead of the one listed. In particular the `$PATH` seen by `sudo` is given in your `sudoers` file:

```
secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Try using `sudo -E` to preserve your environment or use the fully-qualified pathname for `ruby`, or add the paths to `secure_path`, before the ones given.

Comment: This "secure_path" line goes at the end of my /etc/sudoers file?

Comment: @Dave No, it's on the third line of your `/etc/sudoers` file. It's already there in your question :)

Comment: Ah right you are!  Let me give that a go